# Update ruby globally OSX without RVM, Rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, rubymine, rbenv

I am newbie ruby developer. I cannot figure out one annoying thing.

I have macOS sierra installed on my macbook.

When I type `ruby -v` I get following output

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

I am using `RubyMine` IDE as well.

So I've tried to update my ruby globally, I've found different tutorials on the internet, preferred ways are `RVM` and `RBENV`. I tried to install the them but instead of updating ruby globally I got multiple versions of ruby installed in different locations. Because all these tools use different ways for providing ruby binary for current user, but both of them work only for current user because of global `PATH` variable modifications in `.bash_*` files.

So now I feel like a have a lot of garbage left from these tools, I used `find` to remove all folders and occurrences but in Ruby Mine I get following

[http://imgur.com/a/0NzbH](https://imgur.com/a/0NzbH)

I have no idea why `rbenv` and `rvm` are still here as far as  I've removed them from the system. Is there any to get rid of them in Ruby Mine.

But my main question is how can I update ruby **GLOBALLY** in `/usr/bin/` directory without using this annoying tools. I don't need to maintain multiple apps with differen ruby versions, I need global ruby update, so when I type `/usr/bin/ruby -v` I get latest version.

Please help to solve this problem, I have spent a lot of time trying to deal with this `simple` problem.

Thank you

Comment: In my experience when developing with Ruby you will have to run different versions sooner or later. My advise is choose one: `rbenv` or `RVM` (since you absolutely cannot run them together on one machine) and get it to work. There is no advantage in running just one system Ruby version. Therefore I think you should focus on getting you version manager configuration right, not on changing your system Ruby.

Comment: [PSA: Do not use system Ruby](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) (I use [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) in conjunction with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), both are very lightweight)

Comment: Thanks for comments, but I really need only one version and it should be globally available, because I am really doing not much on my laptop, I use another PC for work mostly.

Comment: Then keep the one that came with OSX. That version is available globally. If you want to update then you will be forced to using something outside to manage it (rvm or rbenv).

Answer (score 1):

**Do not overwrite anything in /usr/bin.** macOS doesn't allow this by default, and for good reason. It can break all kinds of unexpected things.

If you want to install the latest version of Ruby globally, the easiest way to do so would be to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Just follow the installation instructions then `brew install ruby` to install the latest version (currently 2.4.0) to /usr/local/bin.

To remove your RVM and rbenv installations, delete .rvm and .rbenv.